# MS Access: Need Longitude and Latitude for both the Origin and Destination Zip Codes in MS Access, in the same row. Can't figure it out

Tags: ms-access, join, datatables, union, zipcode

So I'm currently working on an access database and I have 2 separate tables

**Table 1** (*NDA Postal Summary*) contains:

- Origin Zip
- Destination Zip

**Table 2** (*Zipcode Coordinates*) contains:

- Zip
- Latitude
- Longitude

I am trying to merge Table 1 and Table 2 so that the column headers show as follow:

**Origin Zip** | **Latitude (*For Origin Zip*)** | **Longitude *(For Origin Zip)*** | **Destination Zip** | **Latitude *(For Dest. Zip)*** | **Longitude *(For Dest. Zip)***

[image: Picture of both tables]

Is this possible? Does anyone know how to make this happen? I have posted a picture of the tables above.

Let me know if you need additional details! I'm fairly new to access.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on below query.

```
SELECT Table1.OZip as OZip
, Table2.Lat as OLat
, Table2.Lon as OLon
, Table1.DZip as DZip
, Table2.Lat as DLat
, Table2.Lon as DLon
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN 
Table2 ON Table1.OZip = Table2.Zip;
```

[image]